# What is the best practice for storing a hash?

Tags: storage, database, hash, data-type, blockchain-size

I am about to make the decision on how to store some hash value inside the blockchain. A hash value is the best practice to minimise the size of the blockchain, but still allows people to verify information.

I used the following approach in the past:

```rust
[u8; 16]
```

I found, that in the `pallet_democracy` there is the following approach:

```rust
<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash
```

What way of storing information on-chain is the best, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `<T as frame_system::Config>::Hash` you will use the `Hash` as configured in your runtime. The advantage of this is that it will make your pallet generic over the hashing algorithm to use. If you only use `[u8; 16]` you need to have the hashing algorithm hard-coded to ensure that the hash is only 16 bytes.

Depending on what you are trying to do, there is no downside of any of the solutions. Storage size will only depend on the length of the hash you are using. If you directly specify `[u8; 16]` or use a hash that is 16 bytes the storage usage will be exactly the same.